# Prove that $a-b=b-a\Rightarrow a=b$ without using properties of multiplication.

Tags: calculus

Yesterday my Honors Calculus professor introduced four basic postulates regarding (real) numbers and the operation $+$:

> **(P1)** $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c), \forall a,b,c.$
>
> **(P2)** $\exists 0:a+0=0+a=a, \forall a.$
>
> **(P3)** $\forall a,\exists (-a): a+(-a)=(-a)+a=0.$
>
> **(P4)** $a+b=b+a, \forall a,b.$

And of course, we can write $a + (-b) = a-b$. Then he proposed a challenge, which was to prove that $$a-b=b-a\iff a=b$$ using only these four basic properties. The $(\Leftarrow )$ is extremely easy and we can prove using only **(P3)**, but I'm struggling to prove $(\Rightarrow )$ and I'm starting to think that it is not possible at all.

My question is how to prove $(\Rightarrow )$, or how to prove that proving $(\Rightarrow )$ isn't possible, using only **(P1)**, **(P2)**, **(P3)**, **(P4)**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, it is impossible to prove that result using *only* the information provided.

To show that this is impossible, we can build a system that obeys the postulates, but does **not** satisfy the provided statement.  In particular, we can consider the following system:

- The only numbers are $0$ and $1$
- $1+0=0+1=1$
- $0+0=1+1=0$ (so, $a = -a$ for $a = 0,1$)

Now, show that $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ satisfy $(a-b) = (b-a)$ but $a \neq b$.

---

What you **can** say (once you allow multiplication by integers) is that
$$
a - b = b - a \iff 2(a-b) = (a-b) + (a-b) = 0
$$
in our system, however, multiplying anything by $2$ makes it zero.

Comment: To prove that this system is associative, we just need to verify that it works for the 8 different ways of summing 3 elements from $\{0,1\}$, right?

Comment: @DeathkampDrone that certainly works.  However, I think you can make things easier using the fact that the system is commutative.

Comment: Are you saying that commutativity implies in associativity? Or are you saying that I can use commutative property to reduce the number of cases that I need to verify in order to prove associativity?

Comment: I meant the second, since I'm not sure about the first.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, you can't only from those axioms, and here is why.

Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $1-0=1=0-1$. But $0 \neq 1$.

But you can show this is true if $2 \neq 0$ and your ring is a integral domain, where $2:=1+1$. In fact,

$a-b=b-a \implies a=b-a+b \implies 0=b-a+b-a \implies 0=2b-2a \implies 0=2(b-a) \implies b-a=0 \implies b=a. $

Comment: Good points but you made it a bit hard for this level. :-)

Comment: I don't know what is an integral domain, and I have only a vague idea of what is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so I don't really understand this proof.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Let me try to clear up: you can see $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a shorthand for the structure that Omnomnomnom described. And an integral domain is simply a space where $ab=0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$.